# How to Convert Datetime column header (e.g. 2007-03-01 00:00:00) into Date-Month-Year format i.e. 2007-03-01

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to Convert Datetime column header (e.g. 2007-03-01 00:00:00) into Date-Month-Year format i.e. 2007-03-01?

I tried

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Company Name':['3M India Ltd.','A B B India Ltd.'],'2007-03-01 00:00:00':[1571.30,710.20],'2007-04-01 00:00:00':[710.20,818.13]})
df.columns=pd.to_datetime.date(df.columns)
```

But showing error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'date'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `index` by not datetimes columns by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and if necessary `date`s add [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Company Name')
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).date
print (df)
                  2007-03-01  2007-04-01
Company Name                            
3M India Ltd.         1571.3      710.20
A B B India Ltd.       710.2      818.13
```

Another solution, if not possible first one is possible create `Series` by `columns`, then call [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert all values from columns to datetimes, for not dates is returned `NaT` (missing value for datetimes), so last add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace non datetimes to original columns names:

```
s = pd.Series(df.columns)
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce').dt.date.fillna(s)
print (df)
       Company Name  2007-03-01  2007-04-01
0     3M India Ltd.      1571.3      710.20
1  A B B India Ltd.       710.2      818.13
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce'))
0          NaT
1   2007-03-01
2   2007-04-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```